# Jruby on Rails java object serialization

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jruby

hello dear developers
I have a ruby on rails project that contain some specific logic with java library.
I want to add posibility to render json and xml for this objects in controllers , just like active record serialization.

How can I do it ?

Example of code in controller

```
// Create the ContactWS structure
ContactWS contactInfo = new ContactWS();
// Put some data into it
contactInfo.setPostalCode("12345");
contactInfo.setFaxNumber("555-123456");
contactInfo.setEmail("foo@bar.com");
// Pass the contact info to the user creation call
// This assumes userData is an already filled UserWS structure.
userData.setContact(contactInfo);
// Now create the user
UserWS newUser = api.createUser(userData);
```

newUser is Java value object with private properties and
 getters/setters without any other methods

next I should serialize this object to json

Comment: I tried to create ruby value objects from java objects  and use standart ruby serialization but source code became ugly..

Comment: The question is vague.  Could you provide a code snippet, or pseudo-code, which illustrates what you are wanting to do?

Comment: done , sorry for my english If  I express myself  not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for jruby google-gson will be fine
http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

example

```
include_package "com.google.gson"
gson = GsonBuilder.new.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy::LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES).create()
json = gson.to_json(javaObject)
```